# Group by two fields, and having count() on first field

Tags: oracle, group-by, having

I have a table that stored users play list, a video can be viewed by multiple users for multiple times. 
A records goes like this:

```
videoid, userid, time
123,     abc   , 2013-09-11
```

It means user(abc) has watched video(123) on 2013-09-11

Now I want to find distinct users watched video list (no duplication), and **only show the users that have watched more than two videos**.

```
SELECT videoid, userid 
FROM table_play_list
WHERE SOME CONDICTION
GROUP BY userid, videoid
```

The sql only select distinct users watchlist, I also want to filter users that have watched more than two different videos.

I know I have to google and read the documentation first, some said 'HAVING' could solve this, unfortunately, I could not make it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for users who watched more than two *different* videos.  You can do this by using `count(distinct)` with a `partition by` clause:

```
select userid, videoid
from (SELECT userid, videoid, count(distinct videoid) over (partition by userid) as cnt
      FROM table_play_list
      WHERE <ANY CONDITION>
     ) t
where cnt > 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
SELECT userid, count(*)
FROM   table_play_list
--WHERE SOME CONDITION
GROUP BY user_id
having count(*) >2;
```

Try this if you need to get the count based on userid and videoid(users who watch the same video more than two times).

```
SELECT userid, videoid, count(*)
FROM   table_play_list
--WHERE SOME CONDITION
GROUP BY user_id, video_id
having count(*) >2;
```

Comment: it seems having count(*) filter both userid and videoid. So I got users who watched more than two videos, and also watch a video for more than two times.

Comment: If you need to get the count based on userid and videoid, please find the modified answer.

Comment: Double checked, the second SQL will select userid, and videos which has been watched twice by a same user. I want to get users that have watched more than two videos, and the videolist he watched.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably best handled with analytics (window functions). Without analytics you will probably need a self-join.

```
SQL> WITH table_play_list AS (
  2     SELECT 123 videoid, 'a' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT 125 videoid, 'a' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 123 videoid, 'b' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  5     SELECT 123 videoid, 'b' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 123 videoid, 'c' userid FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT videoid, userid,
  9         COUNT(*) over(PARTITION BY userid) nb_video
 10    FROM table_play_list;
 
   VIDEOID USERID   NB_VIDEO
---------- ------ ----------
       123 a               2
       125 a               2
       123 b               2
       123 b               2
       123 c               1
```

This lists all user/video and the total number of videos watched by each user. As you can see user `b` has watched the same video twice, I don't know if it's possible in your system.

You can filter with a subquery:

```
SQL> WITH table_play_list AS (
  2     SELECT 123 videoid, 'a' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT 125 videoid, 'a' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 123 videoid, 'b' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  5     SELECT 123 videoid, 'b' userid FROM dual UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 123 videoid, 'c' userid FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT *
  9    FROM (SELECT videoid, userid,
 10                 COUNT(*) over(PARTITION BY userid) nb_video
 11            FROM table_play_list)
 12   WHERE nb_video > 1;
 
   VIDEOID USERID   NB_VIDEO
---------- ------ ----------
       123 a               2
       125 a               2
       123 b               2
       123 b               2
```

Comment: A user could watch a video twice. It'd better not use a self-join, because this table has almost 1 million records, I bet.

Answer (score 0):

The below will give users who have watched more than two different videos.

```
 SELECT userid, count(distinct video_id)
 FROM   table_play_list
 WHERE SOME CONDICTION
 GROUP BY user_id
 having count(distinct video_id) >2;
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you use Oracle PL/SQL you can use like this:

> ```
> SELECT column1, column2  
> FROM 
>     (
>     SELECT column1, column2, COUNT(column1)
>     OVER (PARTITION BY column1) AS cnt 
>     FROM test 
>     GROUP BY column1, column2
>     ORDER BY column1 
>     ) 
> WHERE cnt > 2
> ```

- If you use standard SQL you can use like this:

> ```
> SELECT column1, column2 
> FROM test 
> WHERE column1 IN
>     (
>         SELECT column1 
>         FROM
>          (
>              SELECT column1, column2 
>              FROM test 
>              GROUP BY column1, column2 
>              ORDER BY column1
>          )  
>          GROUP BY column1 
>          HAVING COUNT(column1) > 2
>      ) 
> GROUP BY column1, column2 
> ORDER BY column1
> ```